# Given a linear operator $T:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ with $(x_1,x_2,x_3) \mapsto (3x_1,x_1-x_2,2x_1+x_2+x_3)$. Show that $(T^2-I)(T-3I)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Given a linear operator $T:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ with $(x_1,x_2,x_3) \mapsto (3x_1,x_1-x_2,2x_1+x_2+x_3)$.

Show that $$(T^2-I)(T-3I)=0$$

---

The linear operator $T$ is a function such that $$
\begin{bmatrix} 
x_1  \\
x_2\\
x_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
 \mapsto P\begin{bmatrix} 
x_1  \\
x_2\\
x_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad$$
Where $$P=
\begin{bmatrix} 
3& 0 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 0\\
2 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
$$

Moreover $$T^2(x_1,x_2,x_3)=T(3x_1,x_1-x_2,2x_1+x_2+x_3)=(9x_1,2x_1+x_2,9x_1+x_3)$$
$$I(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$$
$$T^2(x_1,x_2,x_3)-I(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(8x_1,2x_1,9x_1)$$
$$T(x_1,x_2,x_3)-3I(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(0,x_1-4x_2,2x_1+x_2-2x_3)$$

But I don't understand what does $(T^2-I)(T-3I)$ means and that's why I can't show the desired result,besides is the matrix $P$ helpful here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(T-3I)(a,b,c)=(0,a-4b, 2a+b-2c)$. Call this vector $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and apply $T^{2}-I$ to it. From your computaion of $T^{2}-I$ is is clear that $(T^{2}-I)(T-3I) (a,b,c)=((8)(0), (2)(0),(9)(0))=0$. Since this is true for all $(a,b,c)$ we conclude that  $(T^{2}-I)(T-3I)=0$.

If you want to use $P$ you have to compute $P^{2}$ and $P^{3}$ and show that $(P^{2}-I)(P-3I)=P^{2}-3P^{2}-P+3I=0$ but that is a lengthy computation.

Answer (score 1):

The given $T$ has a triangular matrix. In this case the diagonal of $T$ shows the eigenvalues. It follows that $T$ can be diagonalized with the numbers $3$, $-1$, $1$ in the diagonal. Since the polynomial $p(z):=(z^2-1)(z-3)$ vanishes at these three places it follows that $p(T)=0$.